# LinkedIn & Slack ignore translated meta tags

Tags: redirects, schema.org, meta-tags, linkedin

Our website is a WordPress site with 2 different languages. Original is German and we use Weglot plugin for translation into English.

So the problem is that LinkedIn and Slack are picking the German metadata when sharing the English version.

Here're meta tags from `https://www.example.com/en/`

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Title in English</title>
    <meta name="description" content="description in english" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/en/" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Title in English" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="description in english" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/en/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Company" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1383" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="1195" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="description in English" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Title in English" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.png" />

    <script type='application/ld+json'>
      {
        "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "@id": "#website",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/",
        "name": "Title in German",
        "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "SearchAction",
          "target": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/?s={search_term_string}",
          "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type='application/ld+json'>
      {
        "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/",
        "sameAs": [],
        "@id": "#organization",
        "name": "Company",
        "logo": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/01\/122.png"
      }
    </script>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.ht/"/
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.ht/en/"/>
```

Every other possible network, incl. WhatsApp and iMessage are displaying correct language.

When I check https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect, I see that it loads all the German meta.

In the URL information it says:

> Fetched URL    `https://www.example.com/en/`
>   Canonical URL    `https://www.example.com/`

URL redirect trail: 1: 200 Success

How do I debug this issue?

Comment: What is your German URL?  Is `example.com` German and `example.com/en/` English?  If so, why do you say one is the canonical of the other.  Canonical tags should not be used across languages, only for duplicate pages.

Comment: For one thing, your script has "Title in German" which might be throwing things off. For another, your hreflang implementation may need to be checked, perhaps there's an error somewhere. There aren't definite solutions, just things that might be affecting the results.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, that's the structure. In the source code of the EN version there's `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/en/"/>` I don't really know why LinkedIn shows original URL as canonical. Do you think that could be the reason?

Comment: @HenryVisotski Thats the only german text in the source code of the english version, but LinkedIn pulls all meta from original language. What do you mean by `hreflang` implementation? How that could be related?

Comment: @Nikita When you have two versions of a website targeted to different regions or languages, hreflang metadata helps search engines figure out which version is right for what location. Lack of this metadata, or incorrect implementation, can confuse some crawlers. More here: https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/

Comment: @HenryVisotski Thanks, we actually do have `hreflang` on the page, see my edit, please.

Comment: Not the problem but note that the `<meta>` and `<link>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML and never have.